# Getting group to show on every line

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report with two groups:
[image]

The report Design looks like this:
[image]

This produces a report that looks like this:
[image]

I am wondering how I can have the process (Anodize) show on every line within the division.I cannot get rid of the groups because this is a summary report, and I don't want to show each line item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is going to be to create a column within the Process group, between Process and Division that displays the process field. Then hide the Process grouped column.

Comment: This gets rid of all of the item line and just shows the total. no division or group show at all. Unless I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Hmm... I just got a report to do what I suggested. Another way might be even easier: once you add the new column that shows the process on every line, delete the column with the process group. You should get a dialog box asking if you want to delete just the column, or the group with it. If you choose just the column, you should get the result you want